# Graph Laplacian to Continuous version

Tags: graph-theory, dg.differential-geometry, laplacian, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Has there been a study of vector laplacian that is a continuous version of a graph laplacian? Is there a good introduction to the topic?

Comment: Have you seen http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66892/is-the-laplacian-on-a-manifold-the-limit-of-graph-laplacians ?

Comment: Would it make sense to consider the Laplacian of a graphon? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphon and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348280/graphons-and-graphs