# Laplacians on graphs vs. Laplacians on Riemannian manifolds: $\lambda_2$?

Tags: graph-theory, dg.differential-geometry, reference-request

A graph $G$ is connected if and only if
the second-largest eigenvalue $\lambda_2$ of 
the [Laplacian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) of $G$ is greater than zero.
(See, e.g.,
the [Wikipedia article on algebraic connectivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_connectivity).)

> Is there an analogous statement for
>   the eigenvalue $\lambda_2(M)$ of the [Laplacian operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator)
>   $\Delta$ for an $n$-dimensional <strike>connected,</strike> closed
>   Riemannian manifold $M$?

($\Delta(f) = \nabla^2(f) = −\mathrm{div}(\mathrm{grad}(f))$.)

I am trying to understand the relationship between Laplacians
on graphs and Laplacians on Riemannian manifolds.
Pointers to help elucidate the connection would be greatly appreciated!

**Addendum**. See Richard Montgomery's interesting new comment on the Laplacian on the integer lattice.

Comment: I don't understand why you require that $M$ is connected. Isn't it true in both cases that the space of harmonic functions is precisely the space of locally constant functions, so its dimension is the number of connected components? 

Comment: @Qiaochu: Well, maybe that is precisely what I am missing, I have overdefined $M$...

Comment: (Above I need to assume that the graph has finitely many connected components.) 

Comment: If the manifold has finitely many connected components, then L^2(M) decomposes as direct sum over the L^2 spaces of the separate connected components. Every connected component contribute the constant space $$\mathbb{C}\cdot 1$$ to be an eigenvector of eigenvalue $0$, hence the multiplicity of the the eigenvalue $0$ equals to the number of connected components. The connection between graphs and manifolds is more explicit by approximating the manifold with its 1 skeleton structure see in the book by Lubotzky - http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~alexlub/BOOKS/On%20property/On%20property.pdf , p.34

Comment: This is a general comment about the relation between the laplacian graph and the one on Riemannian manifold. Suppose $M$ compact and let $T$ be a triangulation of $M$. Given $n\in\mathbb N$ denote by $T_n$ the triangulation of $M$ obtained by $T$ doing $n$-times a barycentric subdivision of $T$. Denote by $\Delta_n$ the discrete Laplacian of the natural connected graph constructed on the 1-skeleton of $T_n$. It is possible that $\Delta_n$ converges in some suitable sense to $\Delta$ and this should give some transference principle. 

Comment: For instance, if the manifold is not connected, then the graph on the any triangulation $T_n$ is not connected and maybe you can get the analogue that you are looking for.

Comment: This probably won't answer your question directly, but I got a lot of useful references in the responses to this question:

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66892/is-the-laplacian-on-a-manifold-the-limit-of-graph-laplacians

Comment: Thanks Asaf, Valerio, and Paul--All very useful comments!

Comment: It is apparently an open (and fun) question to compute
explicitly the fundamental solution to the Laplacian on the integer lattice.  Google `lattice Green's functions' to get some of the literature.  Maybe it is not even possible. 

Kleiner recently began a new branch of research by reproving Gromov's main theorem from `Groups of Polynomial Growth' by using harmonic maps on the Cayley graphs of these groups. 

Comment: Juergen Jost and coworkers have been looking at this relation for some time. See for instance arxiv.org/pdf/0910.3118 , where they present some "dual" Cheeger bound for their last Laplacian eigenvalue (last since they work with some normalized version). The "primal" bound relates the Cheeger constant to the "first" Laplacian eigenvalue, and from the expression for the Cheeger constant one can read easily the "connection" to connectedness both in the discrete and continuous cases. See also http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~fan/wp/cheeger.pdf

Answer (score 12):

In my opinion,  Colin de Verdiere's book ["Spectre de Graphes"](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~ycolver/All-Articles/98a.pdf)   is  the best place to start  investigating  the connection between the discrete Laplacian  and the manifold Laplacian.

Recently,  investigations in computer science (machine learning)   lead to considerable progress.

Pick a "cloud" of points  in a Riemann manifold.  Consider the complete graph with vertices on these points.  Next add weights to the edges   that  correlate with the geodesic distance between the corresponding points on the manifold. Then  form a certain weighted  Laplacian  associated to this weighted  graph.  This  operator converges  with  probability one to the  the manifold Laplacian as the cloud  is bigger and bigger  and is chosen randomly   with respect to the  metric volume measure on the manifold.

I  know  I skipped many details, but  you can get precise statements in this nice paper by M. Belkin and P. Niyogi:

[Towards a Theoretical Foundation for Laplacian-Based Manifold Methods](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~mbelkin/papers/TT_JCSS_08.pdf)

M. [Belkin's webpage](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~mbelkin/)  has  additional info.

Comment: @Liviu: Very nice re cloud converging to manifold Laplacian!  Thanks!

Comment: Belkin and Niyogi have a paper called "Convergence of Laplacian Eigenmaps" where they  show that the spectrum of the above weighetd discrete Laplacian converges to the spectrum of the   manifold Laplacian.

Answer (score 7):

Take a finite cover $\cal{U}$ of $M$ by open subsets, and view the nerve $N({\cal U})$ of this cover as a finite simplicial complex, carrying a combinatorial Laplace operator in each degree. By choosing $\cal{U}$ carefully, with a small enough mesh, in all degree $p$ you may approximate the $k$ first eigenvalues of the Laplace-Beltrami operator on $p$-forms of $M$, by the corresponding eigenvalues of the combinatorial Laplace operator in degree $p$ on $N({\cal U})$. Here $k=s_p({\cal U})-b_p(M)$, where $s_p({\cal U})$ is the number of $p$-simplices. See Theorem 3.1 in a paper by T. Mantuano
http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609599.pdf
Reference: Discretization of Riemannian manifolds applied to the Hodge Laplacian, Tatiana Mantuano, Source American Journal of Mathematics, Volume 130, Number 6, December 2008, pp. 1477-1508

Comment: @Alain: Your reference is precisely on point.  That paper's introduction gives a useful summary of discretizing a manifold to study the spectrum of its Laplacian.  Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

Hi,

1. Note that in either case (graph or manifold) several Laplace Operator discrtizations exists (with different properties). Some of these do not converge to the true (continuous) operator when mesh size is reduced. Higher order FEM approaches can yield fast convergence. Most operators are linear approximations.
2. On the manifold discretization (usually triangles for surfaces), you have geometric information, e.g. the angles between edges, which does not necessarily exist in the graph case.
3. For any operator on a manifold (mesh) that discretizes the contniuous Laplacian this holds:
   the eigenvalues are a diverging sequence of real positive numbers (including zero, and of course the number of eigenvalues is limited by the discretization).
   The first eigenvalue is zero if the manifold is closed, or if the Neumann boundary condition is applied at the boundary. It is larger zero for Dirichlet boundary condition.
   Iff you have n eigenvalues that are zero, you have n connected components.

There may be easier ways of testing connectedness (e.g. using the mesh representation, Euler characteristic or flooding algorithms).